# how to update existing cells in a range with new values ( size of df_old = 100* 30(already on sheet) & df_new= 100*30) in gspread python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, gspread

this code uses old gc this doest work

## open

sh = gc.open_by_url('url')

## select sheet

wks = sh[0]

## update the first sheet with df, starting at cell B2.

wks.update_cells(crange='A2',values = df)

Comment: If the pandas df contains the updated values anyway, and you're just wanting an updated version of the df onto the spreadsheet you can just use `wks.update([df.columns.values.tolist()] + df.values.tolist())`. This would be 1 request and would update your sheet.

Comment: hi kelo write now i am using link bases google authentication should i use API method for updating cells using ur code